# Intermittent BridgeHandler & PublishSubscribeChannel call when gateways' reply channel is pub/sub

Tags: spring-integration

I'm seeing weird behaviour when sending data through my channels. I'm using SI gateway when sending a message to be processed. The gateway is setup as below

```
<integration:gateway id="rptPubGateway"
    default-request-channel="rptPubInChannel"
    default-reply-channel="rptOutputAvailableChannel"
    default-reply-timeout="60000"
    service-interface="xxxx.RptPubGateway" />
```

The reply channel is being set up as a publish/subscribe channel

```
<integration:publish-subscribe-channel id="rptOutputAvailableChannel" />
```

The last service that processes the message is being declared as below

```
<integration:service-activator input-channel="rptOutputAvailableChannel" ref="requestMessageHandler" method="rptIsDone" output-channel="nullChannel"/>
```

Now, the issue that i have is that while the code works fine most of the time, it fails sometimes. When everything works fine the last component processing my message is PublishSubsChannel

```
 PublishSubscribeChannel - preSend on channel 'rptOutputAvailableChannel'
```

but when it fails the last component becomes BridgerHandler

```
BridgeHandler@e851a798' sending reply Message:
```

I should mention that there are no exceptions being thrown while processing my message. (after the failure I can always resend the same message and everything will work OK)

I'm not sure how that BridgerHandler gets created. From what I know this bridge gets created for pub/subs channels but then why I don't see it in the log when everything works fine ?

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "fails" what do you mean?

What are the other consumers on `rptOutputAvailableChannel`?

The `BridgeHandler` you see is an internal bridge to the message's `replyChannel` header, which is where the reply ultimately must go. When explicitly sending to `rptOutputAvailableChannel`, the bridge handler is **always** invoked to get the reply to the message's temporary reply channel.

Comment: Once the _BridgeHandler_ gets called i'm getting 'ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available' error. The _rptOutputAvailableChannel_ has a) one service-activator subscriber client (see my original question) that has a nullChannel on the output, b) two other gateways i.e. <integration id="" ... default-reply-channel="rptOutputAvailableChannel"

Comment: It means the message being sent to the reply-channel has lost it's `replyChannel` header. You can't send arbitrary messages to the reply channel, it must contain the `replyChannel` header from the inbound message - that's how the framework correlates the reply to the request. "Two other gateways..." - you can't have multiple gateways using the same reply channel; replies have to always go to the gateway that initiated the flow.

Comment: **Re: "replyChannel header"**, i'm not sending any arbitrary message to my channel, but i agree that somehow these headers get lost. Is there any way to debug what changes my message ? **Re:"Two other gateways"**, these are different entry points for the same payload i.e. gateway1 takes as an input XML, while gateway2 gets called from some other service with the same payload (XML). In both cases the processing chanin finishes calling the same service activator (thats why my replyChannel has been declared as pub/subs)

Comment: Right, but you can't have multiple gateways with the same reply channel - otherwise every gateway will get the reply from a request. Given the way the bridge works, it will work ok but (in newer versions of the framework) you will get warnings about late replies from the other instances. You would be much better off not declaring a reply-channel and let the framework take care of the routing. Just don't include an `output-channel` on the final endpoint. Turn on DEBUG logging and you should see where the `replyChannel` header is getting lost.