# Spring integration service-interface gateway reply channel as shared Pub/Sub

Tags: spring, spring-integration, gateway

This is similar to [Intermittent BridgeHandler & PublishSubscribeChannel call when gateways' reply channel is pub/sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457631/intermittent-bridgehandler-publishsubscribechannel-call-when-gateways-reply-c) but the scenario is different in that the reply-channel is not getting "lost". The question is what is the best resolution for my scenario.

I am using Spring integration to launch Spring batch jobs. I have a number of input routes e.g. file polling and http requests. These all route to a batch-int Job Launching Gateway. The referenced Job Launcher has a task executor so job launches are asynchronous. This gateway replies on a specified channel.

```xml
<int:gateway service-interface="c.c.c.etl.gateway.JobSubmissionService" id="jobSubmissionService" default-request-channel="jobLauchInputChannel" default-reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel">
</int:gateway>

<int:bridge id="filePollerBridge" input-channel="filePollerOutputChannel" output-channel="jobLauchInputChannel" />

<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="jobLauchInputChannel" reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" job-launcher="jobLauncher">
</batch-int:job-launching-gateway>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel" />

<int:bridge id="jobLaunchReplyChannelBridge" input-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" output-channel="loggingChannel">
</int:bridge>
```

This specified channel 'jobLaunchReplyChannel' is pub/sub and has a logger listening to it. This channel is also used as the reply channel for a service-interface gateway.

The issue I am having is that when jobs are requested via sources that are not the gateway (e.g. the poller) the Bridge that is added by gateway throws an exception because no reply channel is set on replies.

I have resolved this by adding a header to messages sent via the gateway and filtering out messages only with this header to a new 'gatewayReplyChannel'.

```xml
<int:gateway service-interface="c.c.c.etl.gateway.JobSubmissionService" id="jobSubmissionService" default-request-channel="httpJobRequestInputChannel" default-reply-channel="jobSubmissionServiceReplyChannel">
  <int:default-header name="isJobSubmissionServiceMessage" value="true" />
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="jobSubmissionServiceReplyChannel"></int:channel>

<int:filter id="jobSubmissionServiceReplyChannelFilter" input-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" expression="headers.get('isJobSubmissionServiceMessage') == null ? false : headers.get('isJobSubmissionServiceMessage')" output-channel="jobSubmissionServiceReplyChannel"
throw-exception-on-rejection="false" />
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: JIRA [INT-3660](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3660) raised

Answer (score 0):

Eh.. That's an interesting issue. The main cause is because `MessagingGatewaySupport` creates `replyMessageCorrelator` endpoint for an internal `BridgeHandler`.

And we really have that strange behaviour when we send message to the `reply-channel`  directly. That `BridgeHandler` tries to send message to the `replyChannel` from headers.

And we really can't do anything to prevent that logic. And can't protect that explicit `reply-channel` from direct messages.

I think your solution is correct. Another way to overcome that: add `replyChannel` header from the start of another flow (file polling in your case) just using something like this:

```
<header-enricher>
  <reply-channel ref="nullChannel"/>
</header-enricher>
```

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) issue on the matter and we'll take a look what we can do. At least we can document these specifics.

Comment: While Adding nullChannel would be fine in my case. It would cause issues if you had two gateways listening as there would be two bridges and they would both send messages along the reply channel duplicating the reply. The way that I would like it to work would be that the gateways only respond to message that they initated a la [Pub/Sub Topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern#Message_filtering). Will raise the JIRA.